# How can transform a data.frame with factor in the first column to datatype

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2, type-conversion

I have a question about how to format a column's datatype to use in ggplot.

I have a variable that I called "dat1", which is a matrix made of a characters

```
dat1 <- c("2017-07-14 18:00:00", "2017-07-14 19:00:00","2017-07-14 20:00:00","2017-07-14 21:00:00", "2017-07-14 22:00:00", "2017-07-14 23:00:00")
dat1=as.matrix(dat1)

> class(dat1)
 "matrix"

> class(dat1[,1])
 "character"
```

"mean_hour" is another variable, which is a matrix of numeric type

```
mean_hour <- c(132,134,432,233,564,345)
mean_hour=as.matrix(mean_hour)

> class(mean_hour)
[1] "matrix"

> class(mean_hour[,1])
[1] "numeric"
```

Then I made a data.frame with dat1 and mean_hour:

```
med_horaria_plot <- data.frame(dat1,mean_hour)
```

This data.frame stayed this way:

```
> med_horaria_plot

             dat1                     mean_hour
             1 2017-07-14 18:00:00       132
             2 2017-07-14 19:00:00       134
             3 2017-07-14 20:00:00       432
             4 2017-07-14 21:00:00       233
             5 2017-07-14 22:00:00       564
             6 2017-07-14 23:00:00       345

> class(med_horaria_plot[,1])
[1] "factor"

> class(med_horaria_plot[,2])
[1] "numeric"

> class(med_horaria_plot)
[1] "data.frame"
```

This is a smaller version-- the full data.frame is much larger, and when I plot in ggplot, the dates on the x-axis are all superimposed

How can I change the type of these columns so that I can use them in ggplot, then choose the hours I want on the plot in order to avoid overlaps

Comment: It isn't clear what datatype you would like these columns to be transformed to--I'm guessing POSIXct for `dat1` and numeric for `mean_hour`? Also are you using `dat1` as the x-axis in your attempted plot?

Comment: sorry my fail.
dat1 have to be a datatype
mean_hour a numeric
I would like any datatype wich ggplot2 read and I can make a changes in the x-axis (factor type for example is not permited).
Yes, dat1 is a x-axis and mean_hour the y-axis

Comment: Can you add the code you used to make your plot in ggplot? It might help get a clearer idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = med_horaria_plot, aes(x = dat1, y = (med_hour)),group=1,linetype=1)

I just wanna make a plot x,y with this 2 variableAs the dat1 variable has a very large size, placing it on the x-axis in the plot overlaps the dates
I want to be able to select only a few dates to be displayed on the x axis without showing the full datas.
My problems is,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `dat1` column to `POSIXct` (one of two date formats accepted by ggplot) in a straightforward manner:

```
med_horaria_plot$dat1 <- as.POSIXct(med_horaria_plot$dat1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Then plot as usual, as ggplot tends to handle labels on `POSIXct` data quite well by itself:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = med_horaria_plot, aes(x = dat1, y = (mean_hour)),group=1,linetype=1)
```

If you still want to change the labels, you can try `scale_x_datetime()`:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = med_horaria_plot, aes(x = dat1, y = (mean_hour)),group=1,linetype=1) +
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%b %d")
```